# PHP function getting confused with a second parameter/argument

Tags: php, function, arguments

At the end of all of my scripts, I run a function `closeConnection`, i.e.:

```
closeConnection("success");

function closeConnection($note) {
    if ($note === "success") { $append = "?success"; }
    if ($note === "blank") { $append = "?blank"; }
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: index.php" . $append . "");
    exit();
}
```

This runs smoothly.

However, I now want my `closeConnection()` function to take two arguments, so that I can choose a different page to redirect to. This is how it looks the second time around:

```
closeConnection("updated", "view");

function closeConnection($note, $header) {
    $header = $header; // Not sure if needed, doesn't work with or without.
    if ($note === "updated") { $append = "?updated"; }
    if ($note === "blank") { $append = "?blank"; }
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: " . $header . ".php" . $append . "");
    exit();
}
```

Desired result: Redirect to `view.php?updated`

Actual result: Redirect to `.php?blank`

Comment: Is your actual result ".php?blank" or ".php?"

Comment: Why would you expect to see `?updated` when it isn't set in any way? The only possibilities are `?success` if you pass `success`; `?blank` if you pass `blank` or nothing if you pass anything else (e.g. `view`)

Comment: `$header = $header;` ???

Comment: `$header = $header;` => no need to do that ;)

Comment: Sorry, copied in the wrong `if` statement from my code (there are numerous). Correct one should be in there now. And `$header = $header` is there because I wasn't sure if I'd need to "pull in" the argument to the function... these are all new to me. Actual result is `.php?blank`

Comment: I tested and it should work fine. Copy and paste code into this site http://writecodeonline.com/php/ if it works ok there then maybe there is something else wrong somewhere. You can also remove $header = $header

Comment: @mpdc did you get it working? Echo out your header line to see what you get

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you are calling `closeConnection("updated");` somewhere before the `closeConnection("updated", "view");` and you forgot to remove it or something.

Make sure you didn't forget previous commands, and that you are in fact saving the right file.